# kafka Transactional producer example

Tags: spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-transactions-api

I get a message from a source-topic. Then I split the message into 3 parts and send every parts to 3 different topics.
Now 2 messages are delivered to 1st 2 topic successfully. But while sending 3rd message we get exceptions  (e.g. ProducerFencedException | OutOfOrderSequenceException | AuthorizationException | RecordLengthException)

How to roll back / revert 2 other messages from the previous 2 topics ?

Full Java Code example will be very helpful. Dont want to use producer.initTransactions() kind of methods.

I refer this also - [Transactional Kafka Producer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520399/transactional-kafka-producer)
but have doubt really we need to - write all the @Bean for Producer, template, factory , Tx - because those can easily e provided in application.yml.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions

Spring Boot will automatically configure a `KafkaTransactionManager` bean into the container factory when the `transactionIdPrefix` property is set; the container will then start the transaction and if any of the publishing fails, they will all roll back.

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> kafkaTransactionManager(ProducerFactory<?, ?> producerFactory) {
    return new KafkaTransactionManager<>(producerFactory);
}
```

Comment: did a detail post - that it is not working - can you please check   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591355/kafka-transaction-rollback-not-working-with-3-topics-for-recordtoolargeexception