# Kafka transaction rollback not working with 3 topics for RecordTooLargeException

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-transactions, kafka-transactions-api

I post 3 message to 3 topics - while posting if gets exception - all messages will be rolled back.

But in my case it is not happening when I simulate the below exception for 3rd Topic.
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.**RecordTooLargeException**: The message is 117440606 bytes

while posting large message to the **3rd topic (price topic)**- I **programmatically increase the Size** of the message to get exception.

**Message are send to 1st 2 topic successfully - 3rd one failed.**  - As per transaction all messages must be rolled back - but topic 1 and 2 all the time gets the message.

**But LOG shows - Transaction rolled back**

HOW to FIX this issue

### Log

```
2022-03-23 21:16:59.690 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  c.a.m.r.producer.KafkaProducer - @@@ --- Sending Data to  Item , price, Inventory  ----- 
2022-03-23 21:16:59.733 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.s.LoggingProducerListener - Exception thrown when sending a message with key='String' and payload='{"sku":"String","lowestOriginalPrice":...' to topic PRICE-TOPIC: 
**org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException**: The message is 117440606 bytes when serialized which is larger than 1048576, which is the value of the max.request.size configuration.
2022-03-23 21:16:59.733 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.producer.KafkaProducer - [Producer clientId=raw-item-producer-client-2, transactionalId=tx-5b01ad71-f754-44e0-9c52-4774a482bc1d0] Aborting incomplete transaction 
2022-03-23 21:16:59.737 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.producer.KafkaProducer - [Producer clientId=raw-item-producer-client-1, transactionalId=tx-5b01ad71-f754-44e0-9c52-4774a482bc1draw-item-processor-group-id.OSMI_C02_CATALOG_MKPDOMAIN.0] **Aborting incomplete transaction** 
2022-03-23 21:16:59.738 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - Transaction rolled back 
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.albertsons.mkp.rawitemprocessor.consumer.KafkaConsumer.receive(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws java.io.IOException' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 117440606 bytes when serialized which is larger than 1048576, which is the value of the max.request.size configuration.; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 117440606 bytes when serialized which is larger than 1048576, which is the value of the max.request.size configuration.

2022-03-23 21:17:00.250 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  c.a.m.r.producer.KafkaProducer - @@@ --- Sending Data to  Item , price, Inventory  ----- 
2022-03-23 21:17:00.294 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.s.LoggingProducerListener - Exception thrown when sending a message with key='String' and payload='{"sku":"String","lowestOriginalPrice":"String","lowestPrice":"String","updatedAt":"String","createdA...' to topic PRICE-TOPIC: 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 117440606 bytes when serialized which is larger than 1048576, which is the value of the max.request.size configuration.
2022-03-23 21:17:00.295 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.producer.KafkaProducer - [Producer clientId=raw-item-producer-client-2, transactionalId=tx-5b01ad71-f754-44e0-9c52-4774a482bc1d0] Aborting incomplete transaction 
2022-03-23 21:17:00.298 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.producer.KafkaProducer - [Producer clientId=raw-item-producer-client-1, transactionalId=tx-5b01ad71-f754-44e0-9c52-4774a482bc1draw-item-processor-group-id.OSMI_C02_CATALOG_MKPDOMAIN.0] **Aborting incomplete transaction** 
2022-03-23 21:17:00.308 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.l.**KafkaMessageListenerContainer - Transaction rolled back** 
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.albertsons.mkp.rawitemprocessor.consumer.KafkaConsumer.receive(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws java.io.IOException' threw exception; nested exception is **org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed**; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.**RecordTooLargeException**: The message is 117440606 bytes when serialized which is larger than 1048576, which is the value of the max.request.size configuration.; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 117440606 bytes when serialized which is larger than 1048576, which is the value of the max.request.size configuration.
```

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rolled back records remain in the log.

Kafka adds a marker to the log to indicate whether the transaction was committed or rolled back.

By default, consumers will receive all records, even if they are rolled back.

Consumers must be configured with `isolation.level=read_committed` to avoid seeing rolled back records.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_isolation.level

> Controls how to read messages written transactionally. If set to `read_committed`, `consumer.poll()` will only return transactional messages which have been committed. If set to `read_uncommitted` (the default), `consumer.poll()` will return all messages, even transactional messages which have been aborted. Non-transactional messages will be returned unconditionally in either mode.

> Messages will always be returned in offset order. Hence, in `read_committed` mode, `consumer.poll()` will only return messages up to the last stable offset (LSO), which is the one less than the offset of the first open transaction. In particular any messages appearing after messages belonging to ongoing transactions will be withheld until the relevant transaction has been completed. As a result, `read_committed` consumers will not be able to read up to the high watermark when there are in flight transactions.

When using Spring Boot, it's `read-committed`, not `read_committed`.

```
spring.kafka.consumer.isolation-level=read-committed
```

Your IDE should suggest proper values.

Or

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties=isolation.level=read_committed
```

**EDIT**

(Although I see that Boot works with `read_uncommitted` too).

This works as expected for me.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So71591355Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So71591355Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so71591355", topics = "so71591355")
    void listen1(String in) {
        System.out.println("committed: " + in);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so71591355-2", topics = "so71591355",
            properties = "isolation.level:read_uncommitted")
    void listen2(String in) {
        System.out.println("uncommitted: " + in);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so71591355").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        template.setAllowNonTransactional(true);
        return args -> {
            template.send("so71591355", "non-transactional");
            try {
                template.executeInTransaction(t -> {
                    t.send("so71591355", "first");
                    t.send("so71591355", "second");
                    t.send("so71591355", new String(new byte[2000000]));
                    return null;
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.isolation-level=read-committed

spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix=tx-
```

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.4)

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 2000088 bytes when serialized which is larger than 1048576, which is the value of the max.request.size configuration.
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:660)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:403)
    at com.example.demo.So71591355Application.lambda$1(So71591355Application.java:49)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction(KafkaTemplate.java:507)
    at com.example.demo.So71591355Application.lambda$0(So71591355Application.java:44)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:768)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at com.example.demo.So71591355Application.main(So71591355Application.java:19)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 2000088 bytes when serialized which is larger than 1048576, which is the value of the max.request.size configuration.
uncommitted: non-transactional
committed: non-transactional
uncommitted: first
uncommitted: second
```

**EDIT2**

Your application is working as expected; when I add

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "otherApp", topics =  { "ITEM-TOPIC", "INVENTORY-TOPIC", "PRICE-TOPIC" })
void listen3(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
    System.out.println("so71591355 from " + topic + ": " + in);
}
```

to another application, it receives no data.

> 2022-03-24 10:04:57.939  INFO 15038 --- [   hisApp-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : otherApp: partitions assigned: [PRICE-TOPIC-0, ITEM-TOPIC-0, INVENTORY-TOPIC-0]

Of course, with a console consumer, we see the messages because the console consumer is not `read_committed`.

And when I comment out the price send; I see

```
so71591355 from INVENTORY-TOPIC: Inventory data : My test Message
so71591355 from ITEM-TOPIC: Item data : My test Message
...
```

**EDIT3**

To customize the after rollback processor; simply add it as a `@Bean` and Boot will wire it into the container factory.

```java
@Bean
AfterRollbackProcessor<Object, Object> arp() {
    return new DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor<>((rec, ex) -> {
        log.error("Failed to process {} from topic, partition {}-{}, @{}",
                rec.value(), rec.topic(), rec.partition(), rec.offset(), ex);
    }, new FixedBackOff(3000L, 2));
}
```

However, you should remove the `excuteInTransaction` call and just do the sends directly on the template. That way, the template will participate in the container's transaction instead of starting a new one.

This example just logs the error; you can add `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` (or any custom recoverer).

Comment: isolation.level=read_committed     already available in the YML file of consumer section

Comment: See the edit to the answer.

Comment: changes that to  isolation-level: read-committed   for spring boot , but still no result - message send 1st 2 topics but not send to 3rd one due to silulated - RecordTooLargeException

Comment: Yes, I see Boot can handle `read_committed` too (even though the IDE complains); however, it works as expected for me; I added a complete example to the answer that shows it working.

Comment: Also tested with 3 different topics - same result - works fine.

Comment: By the way, you are using local transactions, not container-managed transations (no `KafkaTransactionManger` to the `afterRollbackProcessor` is meaningless (but unrelated to this issue).

Comment: no luck for me.   Gives same issue.     by the way can you please provide afterRollbackProcessor  example with KafkaTransactionManger

Comment: Post an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someplace so I can see what is wrong. Strip it down to the absolute bare minimum.

Comment: I added MCRE Code sample  for your references

Comment: Post it as a complete project someplace (like GitHub), so I don't have to copy/paste.

Comment: The code is available - https://github.com/bubaigit/kafka-tx.git       demo_with_executeInTransaction.zip

Comment: Your app is working as expected - see my second edit.

Comment: As per your EDIT 2 , if I create another spring boot application and listen from the topic s , in case of  Tx roll back ( due to price topic ) - I will not receive any message - correct    - But while browsing via KAFKA-TOOLS , why I saw the messages to the Item , and Inventory topic incase of roll back

Comment: It sounds like KAFKA-TOOLS is not creating a consumer with `read_committed` - everything is working just fine. I am not familiar with that tool.

Comment: Thank you -  By the way I need to add -AfterRollbackProcessor  to log the Failed records and post it to DB and DLQ  for this -"executeInTransaction" settings - A clue will be helpful    -

Comment: See the third edit.

Comment: If we use AfterRollbackProcessor , we need to add - @Transactional to use ? do I need to add   factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL); and  factory.setAfterRollbackProcessor(arp());

Comment: No; you don't need `@Transactional`, unless you want to synchronize with some other transaction such as a DB; and you don't need to use manual acks; the container will reliably commit the offsets; by default after all records received by the poll are processed or after each record with `AckMode.RECORD`.

Comment: I added some comments to the On the EDIT3   - please suggest

Comment: In order to commit the offset of the recovered transaction, you have to pass a transactional `KafkaTemplate` into the DARP and set `commitRecovered`. See the javadocs `* @param kafkaOperations for sending the recovered offset to the transaction.
  * @param commitRecovered true to commit the recovered record's offset; requires a
  * {@link KafkaOperations}.`